# Finding the topological genus of a triangulated surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, algorithms, graph-theory

Given is a surface represented through a triangle mesh (as commonly used in computer graphics, with vertices, edges and faces). The surface is known to be "watertight", i.e. no missing faces.

Is there a computationally efficient way to determine the genus (i.e. number of handles) of the surface represented by the mesh?

[I've tagged this as *graph-theory* because I believe this is a graph-theoretical problem, viewing the mesh as graph]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$2-2g=$ number of vertices - number of edges + number of faces ($g$ is the genus and $2-2g$ is the Euler characteristic). In your case number of edges = $3/2$ times number of faces (triangles).

Comment: Oooh nice... I never would've thought that this is so easy

Comment: It's really a god-given (or Euler- and Poincaré-given?) miracle that the Euler characteristic is so easy to compute and contains all the topological information for a surface.

Answer (score 2):

For general orientable surfaces (even if your triangulation is not 3D watertight, e.g., if it is a flat 2D mesh), [Euler characteristic $\chi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) and [genus $g$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) are connected via
$$
\chi = 2 − 2g − b,
$$
where $b$ is the number of boundary components, i.e., the number of connected boundary loops. For a flat triangular mesh without holes, $b=1$; for a cylinder mesh, $b=2$, for a Möbius strip mesh, $b=1$ etc.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Orientable_surfaces).